# Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Baixei esse código Python aqui:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sys import exit
from json import loads
from Tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from math import floor
from random import randint
from itertools import izip
from urllib2 import urlopen
from threading import Thread
from os import system, remove
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP
from socks import socksocket, setdefaultproxy, PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, 
PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5

system('title Kondra\'s xat raid')

globals()['Threading'] = open('./_inc/Threading.txt','r').read()

class Raider:
    def __init__(self, Chat, Name, Avatar, Homepage, Message, Target, Type, Proxy, ID):
        '''
        if Name == '': self.Name = '[Kondra Raid] chubchub (1322212120)'
        else: self.Name = Name
        '''

        self.Chat, self.Name, self.Avatar, self.Homepage, self.Message, self.Target, self.Type = Chat, Name, Avatar, Homepage, Message, Target, Type
        if Threading == '1': Proxy = Proxy.split(':')

        UserID = ID.split('&UserId=')[1].split('&k1')[0]
        UserK1 = ID.split('&k1=')[1].split('&k2')[0]

        self.IP, self.Port = Proxy[0], int(Proxy[1])
        self.ID, self.K1 = UserID, UserK1

        self.Connect()
    def Connect(self):
        try:
            setdefaultproxy(PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, self.IP, self.Port)
            self.Xat = socksocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)

            self.Xat.settimeout(10)
            self.Xat.connect(("fwdelb02-53956973.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com", 10000))

            self.Xat.send('<y r="{0}" v="0" u="{1}" />\0'.format(self.Chat,self.ID))

            Attributes = ElementTree.fromstring(self.Xat.recv(1024).strip(chr(0))).attrib
            print Attributes
            L5 = self.CalculateL5(Attributes['p'],Attributes['i'])

            self.Xat.send('<j2 cb="'+str(Attributes['c'])+'" Y="2" l5="'+str(L5)+'" l4="'+str(randint(1000,5000))+'" l3="'+str(randint(1000,5000))+'" l2="0" d2="1337" y="'+str(Attributes['i'])+'" k="'+self.K1+'" k3="0" c="'+str(self.Chat)+'" f="0" u="'+str(self.ID)+'" n="'+self.Name+'" a="'+self.Avatar+'" h="'+self.Homepage+'" v="0" />\0')

            Data = self.Xat.recv(4096)
            print Data
            if '<c' in Data: self.Connect()
            if '<m t="Limit: ' in Data: sleep(5)
            if '<logout' in Data or '<dup' in Data: self.Connect()
            while self.Xat:
                print Data
                if self.Type == 'Main': self.Xat.send('<m u="'+self.ID+'" t="'+str(self.Message)+'" />\0')
                elif self.Type == 'PC': self.Xat.send('<z u="'+self.ID+'" t="'+str(self.Message)+'" s="2" d="'+self.Target+'" />\0')
                elif self.Type == 'PM': self.Xat.send('<z u="'+self.ID+'" t="'+str(self.Message)+'" d="'+self.Target+'" />\0')
                elif self.Type == 'Both': 
                    pmORpc = randint(1,2)
                    if pmORpc == 1: self.Xat.send('<z u="'+self.ID+'" t="'+str(self.Message)+'" d="'+self.Target+'" />\0')
                    else: self.Xat.send('<z u="'+self.ID+'" t="'+str(self.Message)+'" s="2" d="'+self.Target+'" />\0')
                if len(self.Message) < 5: sleep(1)
                else: sleep(3)
        except Exception, e:
            try:
                self.Connect()
            except: pass

    def CalculateL5(self, P, I):
        Data = open('./_inc/' + P + '.l5','r')
        Json = {}
        I = int(I) % 10000
        One, Two = I % 100, int(floor(I / 100))
        for x in Data:
            Three, Four = x.strip().split(':')
            Json[Three] = Four
        Data.close()
        return Json[str(One)+','+str(Two)]

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.geometry("400x300")
        self.Window.wm_title("Xat Raid - [Made by: Kondra]")
        self.Window.configure(background='#C65D64')

        CLabel = Label(self.Window, text="Chat:", font=("Helvetica", 10))
        CLabel.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        CLabel.place(x=85, y=273)

        self.Chat = Text(self.Window, height = 1, width = 10)
        self.Chat.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        self.Chat.place(x=125, y=273)

        Start = Button(self.Window, text="Start Raid", padx = 10, pady = 4, command = self.Start)
        Start.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')

        Stop = Button(self.Window, text="Stop Raid", padx = 10, pady = 4, command = self.Stop)
        Stop.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')


        ProxyScrape = Button(self.Window, text="Get Proxies", padx = 10, pady = 4, command = self.DoProxies)
        ProxyScrape.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')

        ProxyScrape.pack()
        ProxyScrape.place(x=220, y=265)


        Start.pack()
        Start.place(x=5, y=265)

        Stop.pack()
        Stop.place(x=315, y=265)

        MLabel = Label(self.Window, text="Message (to spam):", font=("Helvetica", 10))
        MLabel.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        MLabel.place(x=150, y=5)

        self.Message = Text(self.Window, height = 1, width = 14)
        self.Message.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        self.Message.place(x=275, y=5)

        TLabel = Label(self.Window, text="Target ID (for pc/pm raiding):", font=("Helvetica", 10))
        TLabel.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        TLabel.place(x=5, y=240)

        self.Target = Text(self.Window, height = 1, width = 11)
        self.Target.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        self.Target.place(x=175, y=240)

        RLabel = Label(self.Window, text="Raid Type (1 = Main, 2 = PC, 3 = PM, 4 = Both):", font=("Helvetica", 10))
        RLabel.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        RLabel.place(x=5, y=215)

        self.Type = Text(self.Window, height = 1, width = 3)
        self.Type.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        self.Type.place(x=295, y=215)

        NLabel = Label(self.Window, text="Name:", font=("Helvetica", 10))
        NLabel.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        NLabel.place(x=5, y=5)

        ALabel = Label(self.Window, text="Avatar:", font=("Helvetica", 10))
        ALabel.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        ALabel.place(x=5, y=35)

        HLabel = Label(self.Window, text="Homepage:", font=("Helvetica", 10))
        HLabel.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        HLabel.place(x=5, y=65)

        self.Name = Text(self.Window, height = 0.8, width = 10)
        self.Name.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        self.Name.place(x=55, y=5)

        self.Avatar = Text(self.Window, height = 0.8, width = 10)
        self.Avatar.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        self.Avatar.place(x=55, y=35)

        self.Homepage = Text(self.Window, height = 0.8, width = 7)
        self.Homepage.configure(foreground='#FFFFFF',background='#C65D64')
        self.Homepage.place(x=79, y=65)
        mainloop()

    def DoProxies(self):
        try: remove("./_inc/proxies.txt")
        except: pass

        print '##################'
        print '#Scraping Proxies#'
        print '##################'

        Link = urlopen('http://sslproxies24.blogspot.com/').read()
        Link = self.getBetween(Link,"<a href='http://sslproxies24.blogspot.com/2017/","'>")
        Link = urlopen("http://sslproxies24.blogspot.com/2017/" + Link).read()
        Link = self.getBetween(Link,'<span style="color: #00cc00;">','</span>')

        Proxies = open("./_inc/proxies.txt","a")
        if Link in open("./_inc/proxies.txt","r").read():
            pass
        else:
            Proxies.write(Link)
            Proxies.close()

        print '###########################'
        print '#Finished Scraping Proxies#'
        print '###########################\n\n'

        print '*******************'
        print '*Filtering Proxies*'
        print '*******************'

        sleep(2)
        IDs = [i.strip() for i in open('./_inc/ids.txt', 'r')]
        Proxies = [i.strip() for i in open('./_inc/proxies.txt', 'r')]
        for (x,y) in izip(Proxies,IDs):
            try:
                x = ''.join(x)

                z = Thread(target=self.Filter,args=(x,y))
                z.daemon = True
                z.start()
            except: pass

    def Filter(self,Proxy,Blah):
        try:
            P = ''.join(Proxy)
            Proxy = Proxy.split(':')
            setdefaultproxy(PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, Proxy[0], int(Proxy[1]))
            xSock = socksocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
            xSock.settimeout(5)
            xSock.connect(("fwdelb02-53956973.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com", 10003))
            xSock.send('<y r="1" />\0')
            Data = xSock.recv(1024)
            if 'k=' in Data:
                print 'Proxy filtered.'
                pTxt = open('./_inc/filtered.txt','a')
                pTxt.write(str(P) + '\n')
        except: pass

    def getBetween(self,strSource, strStart,strEnd):
        start = strSource.find(strStart) + len(strStart)
        end = strSource.find(strEnd,start)
        return strSource[start:end]

    def Stop(self):
        exit()

    def Start(self):
        Chat = urlopen("http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/roomid.php?d=" + self.Chat.get("1.0", "end-1c")).read()
        Chat = loads(Chat)['id']
        print Chat
        Name = self.Name.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        Avatar = self.Avatar.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        Homepage = self.Homepage.get("1.0", "end-1c") 
        Message = self.Message.get("1.0", "end-1c") 
        Target = self.Target.get("1.0", "end-1c") 

        if Message == '': Message = ' '
        Type = self.Type.get("1.0", "end-1c") 
        if Type == '': Type = 'Main'
        if Type == '1': Type = 'Main'
        elif Type == '2': Type = 'PC'
        elif Type == '3': Type = 'PM'
        elif Type == '4': Type = 'Both'

        Proxies = open('./_inc/filtered.txt', 'r').read()
        Proxies = Proxies.split('\n')

        IDs = open('./_inc/ids.txt', 'r').read()
        IDs = IDs.split('\n')

        if Threading == '1':
            ActiveThreads = []
            [ActiveThreads.append(Thread(target = Raider, args = [Chat, Name, Avatar, Homepage, Message, Target, Type, Proxy, ID])) for Proxy, ID in zip(Proxies, IDs)]

            for Th in ActiveThreads:
                Th.daemon = True
                try:
                    Th.start()
                except: pass
        elif Threading == '2':
            for (Proxy,ID) in zip(Proxies,IDs):
                Proxy = Proxy.split(':')

                Raid = Thread(target=Raider,args=(Chat, Name, Avatar, Homepage, Message, Target, Type, Proxy,ID))
                Raid.daemon = True
                try:
                    Raid.start()
                except: pass
          Gui()
```

E me aparece o erro:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\guilherme_dorneles\Downloads\RAID BY LUKAS\init.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.IP, self.Port = Proxy[0], int(Proxy[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Alguém que entenda de python poderia esclarecer didaticamente o por quê desse erro? Gostaria de além de corrigi-lo aprender a programar em Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lendo por alto, parece que o código tenta ler de um arquivo texto `'./_inc/filtered.txt'` uma lista de proxies com as respectivas portas, separados por `:` tipo assim:

```
 proxy1.com:1234
 algum_outro_proxy.net:3456
 ...
```

O erro está ocorrendo porque, ao ler esse arquivo, o programa encontrou uma linha sem o sinal de `:`. O programa não está preparado para isso, pois, `Proxy.split(':')` retornará uma lista com um elemento só - aí quando ele vai tentar usar essa variável, vai dar o erro "fora da faixa" (*list index out of range*) quando tenta acessar `Proxy[0]` e `Proxy[1]`, nesta linha:

```
self.IP, self.Port = Proxy[0], int(Proxy[1])
```

Para corrigir, existem várias formas, infinitas na verdade. Um exemplo: Você pode adicionar uma verificação para checar se o proxy possui porta:

```
Proxy = Proxy.split(':')
if len(Proxy) < 2:
    print('Proxy sem número de porta no arquivo, será pulado! Verifique!')
    continue
```

O `continue` ali faz ele ignorar o proxy sem porta e ir para o próximo, assim não dará mais erro.

Comment: Nossa! Muito obrigado. Havia realmente um erro ao ler o arquivo filtered.txt, porque havia uma linha vazia. Provavelmente o algoritmo travava quando passava por essa linha vazia.